# How to set keepOutputDirectory to true when using serverless-bundle plugin

Tags: webpack, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture, serverless-webpack-plugin

`serverless-bundle` plugin does not seem to have an option to override `keepOutputDirectory:true`. By default it gets removed on sls deploy command.

How can we keep `.webpack` folder with `.js` and `jsmap` files after deployment as we need it to be able to debug remotely using thundra.

and as specified here: https://apm.docs.thundra.io/node.js/online-debugging it asks for the path where js and js and jsmap files are in case using typescript

Comment: There's an ~ugly~ workaround that apparently works:

Go to node_modules→ serverless_webpack→ lib→ Configurations.js→ SET
keepOutputDirectory: true,

https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle/issues/206#issuecomment-848080560